# How to export test values on Tensorflow

Tags: testing, tensorflow, prediction

I'm using a similar code to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/get_started/regression/imports85.py) as main train/test database and [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/get_started/regression/custom_regression.py) to run the model.
I can print predictions in json but I can't print the test values to see which prediction refeers to each test.

How can I do that?
I'would like to export the tested datas.
Here is my code of import datas

```
# Copyright 2016 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ==============================================================================
"""A dataset loader for imports85.data."""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import collections

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

try:
  import pandas as pd  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
except ImportError:
  pass

# Order is important for the csv-readers, so we use an OrderedDict here.
defaults = collections.OrderedDict([
    ("mes", [""]),
    ("marca", [""]),
    ("linha", [""]),
    ("grupo", [""]),
    ("capacidade", [0.0]),
    ("grade", [0.0]),
    ("custo", [0.0]),
    ("benef", [""]),
    ("desenvolvimento", [""]),
    ("leadtime", [0.0])
])  # pyformat: disable


types = collections.OrderedDict((key, type(value[0]))
                                for key, value in defaults.items())


def dataset(file_name="treino.csv", y_name="leadtime", train_fraction=0.7):
  """Load the imports85 data as a (train,test) pair of `Dataset`.
  Each dataset generates (features_dict, label) pairs.
  Args:
    y_name: The name of the column to use as the label.
    train_fraction: A float, the fraction of data to use for training. The
        remainder will be used for evaluation.
  Returns:
    A (train,test) pair of `Datasets`
  """
  # Download and cache the data
  path = file_name

  # Define how the lines of the file should be parsed
  def decode_line(line):
    """Convert a csv line into a (features_dict,label) pair."""
    # Decode the line to a tuple of items based on the types of
    # csv_header.values().
    items = tf.decode_csv(line, list(defaults.values()),field_delim=';')

    # Convert the keys and items to a dict.
    pairs = zip(defaults.keys(), items)
    features_dict = dict(pairs)

    # Remove the label from the features_dict
    label = features_dict.pop(y_name)
    return features_dict, label

  def has_no_question_marks(line):
    """Returns True if the line of text has no question marks."""
    # split the line into an array of characters
    chars = tf.string_split(line[tf.newaxis], "").values
    # for each character check if it is a question mark
    is_question = tf.equal(chars, "?")
    any_question = tf.reduce_any(is_question)
    no_question = ~any_question

    return no_question

  def in_training_set(line):
    """Returns a boolean tensor, true if the line is in the training set."""
    # If you randomly split the dataset you won't get the same split in both
    # sessions if you stop and restart training later. Also a simple
    # random split won't work with a dataset that's too big to `.cache()` as
    # we are doing here.
    num_buckets = 1000000
    bucket_id = tf.string_to_hash_bucket_fast(line, num_buckets)
    # Use the hash bucket id as a random number that's deterministic per example
    return bucket_id < int(train_fraction * num_buckets)

  def in_test_set(line):
    """Returns a boolean tensor, true if the line is in the training set."""
    # Items not in the training set are in the test set.
    # This line must use `~` instead of `not` because `not` only works on python
    # booleans but we are dealing with symbolic tensors.
    return ~in_training_set(line)

  base_dataset = (tf.contrib.data
                  # Get the lines from the file.
                  .TextLineDataset(path)
                  # drop lines with question marks.
                  .filter(has_no_question_marks))

  train = (base_dataset
           # Take only the training-set lines.
           .filter(in_training_set)
           # Decode each line into a (features_dict, label) pair.
           .map(decode_line)
           # Cache data so you only decode the file once.
           .cache())

  # Do the same for the test-set.
  test = (base_dataset.filter(in_test_set).cache().map(decode_line))

  return train, test


def raw_dataframe():
  """Load the imports85 data as a pd.DataFrame."""
  # Download and cache the data
  path = file_name

  # Load it into a pandas dataframe
  df = pd.read_csv(path, names=types.keys(), dtype=types, na_values="?")

  return df


def load_data(y_name="leadtime", train_fraction=0.7, seed=None):
  """Get the imports85 data set.
  A description of the data is available at:
    https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/automobile
  The data itself can be found at:
    https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data
  Args:
    y_name: the column to return as the label.
    train_fraction: the fraction of the dataset to use for training.
    seed: The random seed to use when shuffling the data. `None` generates a
      unique shuffle every run.
  Returns:
    a pair of pairs where the first pair is the training data, and the second
    is the test data:
    `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = get_imports85_dataset(...)`
    `x` contains a pandas DataFrame of features, while `y` contains the label
    array.
  """
  # Load the raw data columns.
  data = raw_dataframe()

  # Delete rows with unknowns
  data = data.dropna()

  # Shuffle the data
  np.random.seed(seed)

  # Split the data into train/test subsets.
  x_train = data.sample(frac=train_fraction, random_state=seed)
  x_test = data.drop(x_train.index)

  # Extract the label from the features dataframe.
  y_train = x_train.pop(y_name)
  y_test = x_test.pop(y_name)

  return (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)
```

and here is my code to test, evaluate and predict

```
# Copyright 2016 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ==============================================================================
"""Regression using the DNNRegressor Estimator."""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import importar_dados  # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order

STEPS = 100
LT_NORM_FACTOR = 199


def my_dnn_regression_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
  """A model function implementing DNN regression for a custom Estimator."""

  # Extract the input into a dense layer, according to the feature_columns.
  top = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params["feature_columns"])

  # Iterate over the "hidden_units" list of layer sizes, default is [20].
  for units in params.get("hidden_units", [100]):
    # Add a hidden layer, densely connected on top of the previous layer.
    top = tf.layers.dense(inputs=top, units=units, activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Connect a linear output layer on top.
  output_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=top, units=1)

  # Reshape the output layer to a 1-dim Tensor to return predictions
  predictions = tf.squeeze(output_layer, 1)

  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    # In `PREDICT` mode we only need to return predictions.
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode, predictions={"leadtime": predictions})

  # Calculate loss using mean squared error
  average_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)

  # Pre-made estimators use the total_loss instead of the average,
  # so report total_loss for compatibility.
  batch_size = tf.shape(labels)[0]
  total_loss = tf.to_float(batch_size) * average_loss

  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = params.get("optimizer", tf.train.AdamOptimizer)
    optimizer = optimizer(params.get("learning_rate", None))
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=average_loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode, loss=total_loss, train_op=train_op)

  # In evaluation mode we will calculate evaluation metrics.
  assert mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL

  # Calculate root mean squared error
  rmse = tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)

  # Add the rmse to the collection of evaluation metrics.
  eval_metrics = {"rmse": rmse}

  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode,
      # Report sum of error for compatibility with pre-made estimators
      loss=total_loss,
      eval_metric_ops=eval_metrics)


def main(argv):
  """Builds, trains, and evaluates the model."""
  assert len(argv) == 1
  (train, test) = importar_dados.dataset()

  # Switch the labels to units of thousands for better convergence.
  def normalize_lt(features, labels):
    return features, labels / LT_NORM_FACTOR

  train = train.map(normalize_lt)
  test = test.map(normalize_lt)

  # Build the training input_fn.
  def input_train():
    return (
        # Shuffling with a buffer larger than the data set ensures
        # that the examples are well mixed.
        train.shuffle(1000).batch(128)
        # Repeat forever
        .repeat().make_one_shot_iterator().get_next())

  # Build the validation input_fn.
  def input_test():
    return (test.shuffle(1000).batch(128)
            .make_one_shot_iterator().get_next())

  # The first way assigns a unique weight to each category. To do this you must
  # specify the category's vocabulary (values outside this specification will
  # receive a weight of zero). Here we specify the vocabulary using a list of
  # options. The vocabulary can also be specified with a vocabulary file (using
  # `categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file`). For features covering a
  # range of positive integers use `categorical_column_with_identity`.
  marca_vocab = ["ANIMALE","FABULA","FARM","A.BRAND","F.Y.I","MAS ANIMALE"]
  marca = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      key="marca", vocabulary_list=marca_vocab)
  mes_vocab = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
  mes = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      key="mes", vocabulary_list=mes_vocab)
  linha_vocab = ["A+","SEDA","TRICOLINE","MALHA","JNS","SARJA","TECIDO","TECIDO PLANO","DESFILE ABRAND","ARTESANAL",
              "TREND","NOITE","BB","JEANS","HANDMADE","ESI","ALFAIATARIA","PRO","COURO","EST","CONCEPT","OFF PREMIUM",
              "ACESSORIOS","MOVE","NOITE CASUAL","TAT","RESORT","EMI","EMT","FITNESS","BALADA","HOME VESTUARIO",
              "UNIFORME","BOT","VTL","TECIDO PLANO BASICO","HOM","PRAIA","INTIMATES","BTP","TRICOT","QUERO","EMB",
              "ATL","BMA","SAPATO","PRINCESS","BLUE","BOLSA","ESB","TECIDO PLANO ELABORADO","NOVOS DESEJOS","FESTA",
              "FANTASIA","MARKETING","ACE","TECIDO PLANO ESTAMPADO","ADMINISTRATIVO","FAN","TECIDO PLANO LISO","AGA",
              "CDO","AGE","BIJOUX","COBRANDING","NEUTROS","ESM"]
  linha = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      key="linha", vocabulary_list=linha_vocab)
  grupo_vocab = ["VESTIDOS","TOP","TOP NEUTRO","TOP ELABORADO","SHORT","BLUSA","TOP BASICO","BOTTOM BASICO","VESTIDO BASICO",
              "BLUSA ESTAMPADA","BOTTOM","MACACAO","TOP FUN","OVERTOPS","VESTIDO ESTAMPADO","BOTTOM ESTAMPADO",
              "BOTTOM ELABORADO","CALCAS","CAMISA","SAIAS","AGASALHO","CALCA ESTAMPADA","ACESSORIOS","DIVERSOS",
              "CINTOS","BIQUINI","TOP TECIDO","BIQUINI/MAIO","VESTUARIO","OVERTOP ESTAMPADO","CALCINHA","BERMUDA",
              "LINGERIE","MAIO","VESTIDOS ELABORADO","OUTROS","SAPATOS","BOLSAS","CAMISA ESTAMPADA","LENCO","CHAPEU",
              "FANTASIA","OVERTOP PESADO","TOP LEVE","HOME","PRAIA","OVERTOP LEVE","OVERTOP ELABORADO","STREET","ESPECIAL",
              "PIJAMA","CANGA","BRINCO","SOUTIEN","OVERTOP BASICO","UNDERWEAR"]
  grupo = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      key="grupo", vocabulary_list=grupo_vocab)
  benef_vocab = ["S","N"]
  benef = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      key="benef", vocabulary_list=benef_vocab)
  desenvolvimento_vocab = ["INT","EX"]
  desenvolvimento = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      key="desenvolvimento", vocabulary_list=desenvolvimento_vocab)
#  make = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(
#      key="make", hash_bucket_size=50)

  feature_columns = [
      tf.feature_column.indicator_column(mes),
      tf.feature_column.indicator_column(marca),
      tf.feature_column.indicator_column(linha),
      tf.feature_column.indicator_column(grupo),
      tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="capacidade"),
      tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="grade"),
      tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="custo"),
      # Since this is a DNN model, convert categorical columns from sparse
      # to dense.
      # Wrap them in an `indicator_column` to create a
      # one-hot vector from the input.
      tf.feature_column.indicator_column(benef),
      tf.feature_column.indicator_column(desenvolvimento)#,
      # Or use an `embedding_column` to create a trainable vector for each
      # index.
 #     tf.feature_column.embedding_column(make, dimension=3),
  ]

  # Build a custom Estimator, using the model_fn.
  # `params` is passed through to the `model_fn`.
  model = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=my_dnn_regression_fn,
      params={
          "feature_columns": feature_columns,
          "learning_rate": 0.001,
          "optimizer": tf.train.AdamOptimizer,
          "hidden_units": [100,500,100]
      },
      model_dir="resultados")


  # Train the model.
  model.train(input_fn=input_train, steps=STEPS)

  # Evaluate how the model performs on data it has not yet seen.
  eval_result = model.evaluate(input_fn=input_test)
  pred_result = model.predict(input_fn = input_test,
    predict_keys=None,
    hooks=None,
    checkpoint_path=None)
  sess = tf.Session()
  # Print the Root Mean Square Error (RMSE).
  print("\n" + 80 * "*")
  print("\nRMS error for the test set: {:.0f} Dias"
        .format(LT_NORM_FACTOR * eval_result["rmse"]))
  #prediction_df = pd.DataFrame(list(pred_result))
  #prediction_df.to_csv('prediction.csv')
  print(list(pred_result))

  print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # The Estimator periodically generates "INFO" logs; make these logs visible.
  tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
  tf.app.run(main=main)
```

Comment: "similar code" is not the "same code". Small differences can often be crucial. _Your_ code and _your_ desired functionality is the only code that matters for the purpose of the question. Whatever you copied it from is likely not relevant. Post your code here (within the question, not on an external link) and then it might be possible to help you.

Comment: Posted my code. If you can help, I would apreciate a lot. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't know tensorflow at all. I just came across your question in one of the review queues as being low quality, so I commented to help you avoid the question being closed. Hopefully now you have got some useful info in there, someone with the relevant expertise will be able to answer.